# How to make pivoted table editable in HTML PHP SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

This is the table I wanted to make editable. I can do it in a simple table but with this approach, I have difficulty making this table become editable in its cell. I've searched it so many times but I am still not able to solve this problem.

The table looks like this:

[image]

I want the scores (in the EXAM column) to become editable and so updated in its SQL database.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>VSA System</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/vito.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>    
<body>

<div>
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'deped');
$iddd = 6;    
$iddds = 1;
$idddds = 1;
$idyear = 1;


define('THE_NUMBER', 'SC'); // !important
define('THE_TYPE',     'fullname');         // !imortant
define('SCORE',   'component_value');       // !important    

$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT CONCAT(l_name,', ',f_name,' ',m_name) AS fullname, CONCAT(tbl_qa.description,'  /',hps) AS SC, component_value FROM tbl_student, tbl_grade, tbl_qa WHERE tbl_grade.component=3 AND tbl_grade.sub_component=tbl_qa.id AND tbl_student.sid=tbl_grade.stud_id AND tbl_grade.sub_component=tbl_qa.id AND tbl_grade.subject_id=$iddds AND tbl_grade.grading=$idddds AND tbl_grade.year_level=$idyear GROUP BY tbl_grade.hps, fullname ORDER BY tbl_qa.description ASC, tbl_grade.sub_component_number_ex, tbl_grade.hps ASC");

$allType = array();
$sidesql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student, tbl_grade WHERE tbl_student.section=$iddd GROUP BY tbl_student.sid ORDER BY l_name";
$sidesqls = mysqli_query($db,$sidesql);
$arr = array();
while($rowsss = mysqli_fetch_array($sidesqls)){
    $arr = $rowsss['l_name']. ', ' .$rowsss['f_name']. ' '.$rowsss['m_name'];
        array_push($allType , $arr);
}


$outputNumber = array(); 
$currentInputRow = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$r_arr = array();

while (isset($currentInputRow[THE_NUMBER])) { 

  $currentNumber = $currentInputRow[THE_NUMBER];

  $theTypeNumber = array();

  foreach ($allType as $type) {
    $theTypeNumber[$type] = '--';
  }

  while ($currentInputRow[THE_NUMBER] == $currentNumber) { 

    $theTypeNumber[$currentInputRow[THE_TYPE]] = $currentInputRow[SCORE];


    $currentInputRow = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  }

   $currentOutputRowIdx = 0;


   $outputNumber[$currentOutputRowIdx][] = $currentNumber;
   $currentOutputRowIdx++; 



    $item=null;

    $item = explode('/', $currentNumber);


    $score=null;
   foreach ($allType as $outType) {
       $score = $theTypeNumber[$outType];
       if($theTypeNumber[$outType] == '--') {
           $score = 0;
       }


       $r_arr[$currentOutputRowIdx][] = (($score/$item[1])*50+50);

     $outputNumber[$currentOutputRowIdx][] = $theTypeNumber[$outType];
     $currentOutputRowIdx++;
   }

} 




foreach($r_arr as $k => $v) {
    $tt = 0;
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach($v as $k1 => $v2) {
        $cnt++;
        if($v2 == "--") {
            $v2 = 0;
        }
        $tt += $v2;
    }

    array_push($outputNumber[$k], "<b><i>".round($tt/$cnt,2)."</i></b>");
    array_push($outputNumber[$k], "<b><i>".round(($tt/$cnt)*0.20    , 2).'%'."</i></b>");


}

if(count($outputNumber) !=0) {
    array_push($outputNumber[0], "<b>Percentage Score<b>");
    array_push($outputNumber[0], "<b> Weighted Score (20%)<b>");
}




$currentType = -1; 

echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
foreach ($outputNumber as $oneOutputRow) {

  echo '<tr>';

  if ($currentType < 0) {
    echo '<td>'. 'Student' .'</td>';
  }
  else {
    echo '<td  style="text-transform:capitalize;">'. $allType[$currentType] .'</td>';
  }

  foreach($oneOutputRow as $column) {
    echo '<td>'. $column .'</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
  $currentType++; 

}
echo '</table>';

?>
</div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fullDataTable functionalites to load and edit data to page

DataTable has no edit options built in,

but You can do it by connecting it with jEditable jQuery plugin, as described [here](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple)